# Escaping whereRaw query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to do a fulltext search on one of my MySQL database tables in Laravel. I have my search controller looking like this:
    class SearchController extends \BaseController {

```
public function postSearch()
{
        if (Input::has('search')) {
            $q = Input::get('search');
            $q = urlencode($q);
            return Redirect::to('/search/'.$q);
        }
        else
            //TODO: Handle this error
}

public function getSearch($query)
{
    $query = urldecode($query);
    $products =  Product::whereRaw(
            'MATCH(product_name,product_desc,product_category) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)',
            array($query)
        )->paginate(5);
        return View::make('searchResults', array('products' => $products, 'query' => $query));
}
```

I have the separate get/post functions as I was told that pagination is much easier to deal with when the search is done using a GET request; as a result I use the route `Route::get('/search/{query}', 'SearchController@getSearch');` to display the search results.

However, it doesn't seem like the search query is being escaped correctly. I used `urlencode` to prevent the URL from having special characters in it, but when the query is performed, I can still cause errors by searching for `);` or other strings with parentheses or semicolons. (I get `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:` errors).

Am I performing my fulltext query incorrectly, or is there some function I can call to 'prepare' my query string?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using the `e()` function on the input query seemed to do the trick. I guess this is the same as `htmlentities()`

I'm not sure if my `urlencode` is still necessary, but it seems to work fine leaving it in.